# Get real time factor from a headless gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am now trying to tuning the gazebo simulation speed. Is there a way to get a feedback of the real time factor from the gazebo server if i run it headless ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7412/get-real-time-factor-from-a-headless-gazebo/) by [DongDong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1020/dongdong/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I will answer it for myself.  gzstats is the right command for it

---

Originally posted by [DongDong](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1020/dongdong/) with karma: 46 on 2014-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1200/niall/) on 2015-09-11**:
I'm trying to do the same thing but was looking for a way of doing it with a plugin. I found GetRealTime() in a modelplugin but can't find the realtime factor. How did you end up doing it exactly?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-01-27**:
You can subscribe to the `/gazebo/default/world_stats` topic.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `gzstats` command has been replaced with `gz stats`, notice the space between gz and stats. There are many other command utilities, use `gz -h` to see them all. This feature is present in gazebo 5+.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-01-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2